# How to derive/get TFS server info from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to the TFS server hosted by the Visual Studio Online service.

I use https://sigarbor.visualstudio.com/SharingMemories to access the web portal, but I see nothing about what Visual Studio TFS connection dialog box wants

This is what I tried:

[image]

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Comment: @starain-MSFT yes we did. Thought I had tried that but the answer below confirmed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to enter the URL: `https://sigarbor.visualstudio.com`. `SharingMemories` is a team project; you don't need to include the team project when connecting. You'll be able to choose it after you're connected.